# issue installing the react in vs code ,can someone tell me how to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, installation, directory, path

After executing below command in vs code
`PS C:\Users\Dharavath Suman\OneDrive\Desktop\react> npx create-react-app my-app`

```bash
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Dharavath Suman\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Dharavath Suman\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Dharavath Suman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-17T19_30_10_241Z-debug-0.log
```

i tried the command `npx create-react-app my-app` but it showed the errors as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Looks NPM not installed on your machine, please check the NPM and node in your machine

use below command in terminal of VSCode

```
node -v
npm -v
```

Answer (score 0):

**The core issue**: npm is unable to find the directory

**Potential causes**:

- npm might not be installed correctly.
- The installation path might have been altered.
- File permissions within the directory might be incorrect.

**Solution**:

1. Check npm Installation

- Open a command prompt or terminal and type npm -v. If npm is installed correctly, it should output its version number.
- If not installed, download and install the latest version from the official Node.js website: https://nodejs.org/ (npm is bundled with Node.js).

2. Verify Installation Path:

- If npm is installed, check its configured path:
  Open a command prompt or terminal and type `npm config get prefix`.
- If the output doesn't match the missing directory (`C:\Users\Dharavath Suman\AppData\Roaming\npm`), update the path using: `npm config set prefix C:\Users\Dharavath Suman\AppData\Roaming\npm`

3. Check File Permissions:
   Right-click the npm directory, go to **"Properties" -> "Security"** and ensure your user account has **"Full control"** permissions.
4. Reinstall npm (if necessary):
   If the issue persists, consider reinstalling npm:

- Uninstall Node.js completely.
- Download and install the latest version from https://nodejs.org/.